# Extracting .osm from PostGIS database

Tags: postgis, postgresql

How can I extract .osm file from PostGIS database? I've been trying Osmosis:

`osmosis --rp database="gis" user="postgres" password="123" --wb`

gives me an error:

`org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: Task 2-wb does not support data provided by default pipe stored at level 1 in the default pipe stack.`

with `osmosis --rp ... --wb` option:

`SEVERE: Thread for task 1-rd failed
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: Unable to create resultset`

Comment: did you specify an output file?